# Binding Umlauts in tmux

Tags: bind, shortcut, tmux, diacritics

I am a bit new to tmux and currently I try to setup my config. During that setup I tried to bind `C-ö`, which loads without errors during the initialization phase of tmux. But in the end the key mapping is not working. I double checked it with other non-umlaut mapping and it works.

The config line looks like that:

`bind -r C-ö next-window`

I also tried to use different key representations `<C-ö>`, `C-47` and `<C-47>`. But without luck. 
On the other hand when I just map `ö` there is no problem..

Is it even possible to map umlauts in the combination with Ctrl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Terminals support only a small set of Ctrl keys - @, a-z, [, ], \, ^ and function keys like F1 or Up.

You should be able to bind M-ö instead.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification. I tested it with M-ö and that works. From the general workflow this is a bit too much. But then I will test a workaround with M-a as my prefix keys.
Thanks Nicholas.